# Выбор наибольших и наименьших значений при группировке в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть следующие данные:

```
ID  sum ind
1   5   A
1   4   B
1   3   C
1   2   D
2   5   A
2   5   B
2   3   C
3   5   A
3   4   B
3   3   C
3   3   D
```

Необходимо для каждого `ID` выбрать наибольшую и наименьшую `sum` и их `ind`
Если значений несколько, то выбираем первый по алфавиту, то есть на выходе необходимо получить

```
ID  sum ind
1   5   A
1   2   D
2   5   A
2   3   C
3   5   A
3   3   C
```

Код пишется в MS SQL

[Залил данные :](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/305ee/1/0)

Answer (score 3):

С использование аналитической функции:

```
select id, sum, ind 
from (
   select *,
       rank() over (partition by ID order by sum asc, ind asc) as asc_rank,
       rank() over (partition by ID order by sum desc, ind asc) as desc_rank
   from mytable) as m 
where asc_rank = 1 or desc_rank = 1;
```

Этот запрос вернет несколько записей, если у нас, скажем, есть еще одна запись с `sum=5` и `ind=A`. Если нужно чтоб возвращалась только одна, то нужно заменить `rank()` на `row_number()`.